# NoHostAvailableException : Application services not starting

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

We have a cluster running with 36 nodes on the 4.0.1 version & Driver version is 3.10.2. The application team tried to launch the new application on this database but it was failing with the below error. We found the below exceptions from Driver logs & DB logs respectively.

Driver Log Exception:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
cassandra.x.x.x.x.com/x.x.x.x:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Connection thread interrupted),
cassandra.x.x.x.x.com/x.x.x.x:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Connection thread interrupted),
cassandra.x.x.x.x.com/x.x.x.x:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Connection thread interrupted),
```

DB Log Exception:

```
DEBUG [epollEventLoopGroup-5-10] 2023-05-31 11:14:47,837 InitialConnectionHandler.java:153 - Configured pipeline: 
DefaultChannelPipeline{(frameDecoder = org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameDecoderCrc),
(frameEncoder = org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameEncoderCrc),
(cqlProcessor = org.apache.cassandra.transport.CQLMessageHandler),
(exceptionHandler = org.apache.cassandra.transport.ExceptionHandlers$PostV5ExceptionHandler)}
```

The compatible protocol version(V5) was not set in the driver configuration for the apache cassandra 4.0.1 DB version. If not set, Which value does it consider by default?

Could it be because of the protocol version?

Regards,

Mani

Comment: Is the cluster using SSL?

Comment: No, It is not using SSL. Existing applications were able to communicate with the cluster. By using the same code base, The new application was created but was not able to communicate with the DB.

Comment: I think we would need more context to go on - is the new app running on the same servers as the old app? e.g. eliminate any network routing issues. The debug message is not an exception its just a log message (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/f66adb0278aa56e8c2696db6f3fe24d311bf7b44/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/InitialConnectionHandler.java#L153 ) which was changed to a trace message by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17038 in 4.0.2

Comment: "Which value does it consider by default?"  The protocol negotiated between the driver and cluster will be the highest level supported by both of them.  In your case, both the 3.10 driver and 4.0 Cassandra support v5, so that is what it should connect at.  You could certainly try setting it.

Comment: First, I would upgrade to something higher than 4.0.1. The reason I say that is I recall a bug where the driver was using an invalid field. I can't recall all of the specifics, but it was basically that the driver and system.peers tables weren't correct. If possible, upgrade both c* and the driver. You could even just create a small app with latest version of the driver to see what happens.